# How to get Dribbble feed of popular posts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson, dribbble-api

I trying to have a Dribbble feed on a website with the latest popular posts. I'm in doubt if I should register an application via: https://dribbble.com/account/applications/new or can I just use JSON or AJAX to pull out the most recent shots that are posted on Dribbble?

I already tried this, but with no success. I receive the error:

Error:

```
GET https://api.dribbble.com/shots/popular?callback=jQuery111104258300690995278_1471442725999&_=1471442726000 404 (Not Found)
```

JS:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.dribbble.com/shots/popular?callback=?", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('.dribbble-feed').append('<img src="' + data.shots[0].image_url + '" />');
});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWgLaR?editors=1111

### Update

After following the reply given by Karol Klepacki, I receive the following when log data to my console:

[image]

Updated JS:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.dribbble.com/v1/shots/popular?callback=?", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('.dribbble-feed').append('<img src="' + data.shots[0].image_url + '" />');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper address for dribble api is `https://api.dribbble.com/v1/shots`.

Now you have to authenticate yourself. You have to [register application](http://developer.dribbble.com/), and you'll probably get some token, that you have to attach to your requests (Method 2 [from here](http://developer.dribbble.com/v1/#authentication) should be easier for you. Then you will have request like `https://api.dribbble.com/v1/shots/?access_token=TOKEN`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.getJSON("https://api.dribbble.com/v1/shots/?access_token=TOKEN", function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(e){
      $('.dribbble-feed').append('<img src="' + e.images.normal + '" />');
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: It still doesn't work when I use https://api.dribbble.com/v1/shots/popular/?access_token=TOKEN. I replace TOKEN with my `Client Access Token`

Comment: Absolute! :) I get a 404 error. I'm not sure about the slash after popular, but when I remove it, I still receive the 404 error.

Comment: When I use `https://api.dribbble.com/v1/user?access_token=TOKEN` with my Client access token, I receive all info of my Dribbble profile, like url, avatar etc. But not when I would like to list out popular shots of Dribbble. I talk about this request: `https://api.dribbble.com/v1/shots/popular?access_token=TOKEN`. That will leave me with the 404 as mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: https://api.dribbble.com/v1/shots works. However I haven't found the `popular` option in documentation :)

Comment: Oh oke. Shots is perfect. I receive now all objects but they aren't displayed on the page.. Error is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`